# Android how to send multiple contacts are attached in single .vcf file and send to mail?

Tags: android, contacts, vcf-vcard

In my application, a number of contacts are attached to single **.vcf** file and that file sent to mail, try to this one all contacts data display in log cat, but unable to send all data attached to single .vcf file?

Anyone have an idea regarding this help me, please.

here is my code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    vCard = new ArrayList<String>();                 

    Log.i("TAG one", "vfile" +vfile);
    vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".vcf";  

    /**
     * This Function For Vcard And here i take one Array List in Which i
     * store every Vcard String of Every Contact Here i take one Cursor and
     * this cursor is not null and its count>0 than i repeat one loop up to
     * cursor.getcount() means Up to number of phone contacts. And in Every
     * Loop i can make vcard string and store in Array list which i declared
     * as a Global. And in Every Loop i move cursor next and print log in
     * logcat.
     * */
    getVcardString();           
}       

private void getVcardString() { 

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    Log.i("TAG two", "cursor" +cursor);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.i("Number of contacts", "cursorCount" +cursor.getCount());          

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {                       
            get(cursor);                    
            Log.i("TAG send contacts",  "Contact " + (i + 1) + "VcF String is" +  vCard.get(i));                     
            cursor.moveToNext();                                        
        }           

        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
        s.append( vCard.toString());                
        string = s.toString();                           
        file = new File(string);        

    //  Log.i("s", ""+s);   
    //  Log.i("string", ""+string); 
        Log.i("file", ""+file);             

    } else {
        Log.i("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
    }        
}       

public void get(Cursor cursor) {

    String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Log.i("lookupKey", ""+lookupKey);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);     

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");          

        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
        fis.read(buf);
        String vcardstring= new String(buf);          

        String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
        FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, true);
        mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());

        vCard.add(storage_path);            

    } catch (Exception e1)  {            
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}       

private void data() {       

    File filelocation = file;     
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
    sharingIntent.setType("application/x-vcard");             
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));            
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally my issue is solved using like this

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);     

     mContext = this; 

     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);          
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {        
            data();
        }
    });                      

    /**
     * This Function For Vcard And here i take one Array List in Which i
     * store every Vcard String of Every Contact Here i take one Cursor and
     * this cursor is not null and its count>0 than i repeat one loop up to
     * cursor.getcount() means Up to number of phone contacts. And in Every
     * Loop i can make vcard string and store in Array list which i declared
     * as a Global. And in Every Loop i move cursor next and print log in
     * logcat.
     * */
    getVcardString();           
}       

 public static void getVcardString() {   

    String path = null;     
    String vfile = null;

     vfile = "Contacts.vcf";           
    Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);

    phones.moveToFirst();
    Log.i("Number of contacts", "cursorCount" +phones.getCount());  
    for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)   {       

         String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
         Log.i("lookupKey", " " +lookupKey);
         Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
         AssetFileDescriptor fd;

         try  {
             fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
             FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
             byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
             fis.read(buf);
             String VCard = new String(buf);          

             path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
             FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
             mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());    

             phones.moveToNext();               

             filevcf = new File(path);
             Log.i("file", "file" +filevcf);

         }catch(Exception e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();  
         }
    }       
    Log.i("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");          
}

protected void data() {             
    File filelocation = filevcf ;     
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
    sharingIntent.setType("application/x-vcard");       
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "mail@gmail.com" );        
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation.getAbsolutePath()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));            
 }
```

Comment: i dont see where you have been initializing `filedata`.

Comment: i was just stumbled at this so i got here i had fixed my problem but thought for some others it would be useful to tell you :). Just for future response. Thanks

Comment: I had done it by other way. My requirement was different .:) but it would be usefull to others. So giving you +1. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26013/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-bbdev)

Answer (score 3):

I successfully tested the following.  Changes to your code are indicated with comments beginning with "CHANGE:".  Don't forget to have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String vfile;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private ArrayList<String> vCard;
    private String string;
    private File file;
    private String storage_path; //CHANGE:  storage_path global

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vCard = new ArrayList<String>();                 

        Log.i("TAG one", "vfile" + vfile);
        vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".vcf";  

    /**
     * This Function For Vcard And here i take one Array List in Which i
     * store every Vcard String of Every Contact Here i take one Cursor and
     * this cursor is not null and its count>0 than i repeat one loop up to
     * cursor.getcount() means Up to number of phone contacts. And in Every
     * Loop i can make vcard string and store in Array list which i declared
     * as a Global. And in Every Loop i move cursor next and print log in
     * logcat.
     * */
        getVcardString();    
        data(); //CHANGE: now calling data to send vCard intent
    }

    private void getVcardString() { 

       cursor =  getContentResolver().
       query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
       null, null, null, null);
       Log.i("TAG two", "cursor" +cursor);
       if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       Log.i("Number of contacts", "cursorCount" +cursor.getCount());          

       for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {                       
            get(cursor);                    
            Log.i("TAG send contacts",  
            "Contact " + (i + 1) + "VcF String is" +  vCard.get(i));                     
            cursor.moveToNext();                                        
        }           

//            StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(); CHANGE: not needed
//            s.append( vCard.toString());                
//            string = s.toString();                           
//            file = new File(string); //CHANGE: this is not what file should be        

        } else {
            Log.i("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
        }        
    }       

    public void get(Cursor cursor) {

        String lookupKey =     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        Log.i("lookupKey", ""+lookupKey);
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);     

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");          

            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String vcardstring= new String(buf);     
            vCard.add(vcardstring); //CHANGE: added this, so log statement in above method doesn't generate error

//            String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            //CHANGE: this is the path we need to get file for intent:
            storage_path = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + File.separator + vfile;            
            Log.i("MainActivity", storage_path);
            //CHANGE: this will create the file we need:
            file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), vfile);
            file.createNewFile(); //CHANGE
            //CHANGE: this will create the stream we need:
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true); 
            mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());
            mFileOutputStream.close(); //don't forget to close

    //            vCard.add(storage_path); //CHANGE: not needed           

        } catch (Exception e1)  {            
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

    private void data() {     
    //        File filelocation = file; //CHANGE: not what we need    
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");      
        sharingIntent.setType("application/x-vcard"); 
        //CHANGE: using correct path:
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(storage_path));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));            
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not working send mail file is 0k only Thanks for answer my issue is solved updated my answer soon.....

Comment: My solution works for me--when I run it, I get prompted with a list of apps to use to mail the .vcf file, and when I select one of the apps in the list, a 40 KB .vcf file is attached in the new message.  I successfully sent the file to myself, and confirmed that my contacts were in it.  Glad you have a solution, though I'm sorry mine didn't work for you.  I'm curious to know where my solution failed, if you would provide details.  Thanks.