# Dispalying a vcf file in a textview using android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the content of a .vcf file and put it inside a textview, I just started developing so please be specific.

I'm also trying to use ez-vcard but I can't seem to manage.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519448/android-read-contacts-from-vcf-file

Comment: Thnk's ' maybe I should be more specific. I have used the code:Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path.get(position))),"text/vcard");  
     startActivity(intent);                           and all it does is to import it to the contacts . I have used intent filter and it doesn't seem to help.