# how to open .vcf file and upload to the server?

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I am developing an android app in which there is an edittext and two buttons one is for attching .vcf file and other is for sending .vcf file to email id entered in edittext.

All I need to select .vcf file from sdcard and get its path back so that it can be sent to the email id. any help would be greatful.

Comment: Make an effort, at least do a search. There are many answers on SO on that topic.

Comment: @Rajesh I tried but dint find any. if u got any link plz provide me at least.thanks.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798001/android-how-to-send-multiple-contacts-are-attached-in-single-vcf-file-and-send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spoiling a huge amount of timing, I finally got the answer. fetching .vcf file is very easy. It needs some java file concept. Following is the code which will fetch .vcf file from sdcard:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles() {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/VCFFiles");

        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
                if(files[i].getPath().endsWith(".vcf")){
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
                }
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }
```

Comment: Its a really great that you solved with your self. +1 from me.