# Send contact (phone number ) via SMS or Email

Tags: android, contacts

i have been developing an app. It allow call, sms, etc ... from information about contact. Now i want to attach contact via sms,or email. How to do this?? Thank in advance

Comment: You could export it as a VCF file...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582643/how-to-create-one-vcf-file-for-all-the-contact-in-android

Comment: Thanks @Snicolas, i had a VCF of all my contacts. But i don't know how to send it via SMS, email or Bluetooth. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess these can get you started:

[SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)

[Bluetooth](http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/)

[Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401104/android-exporting-to-csv-and-sending-as-email-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

You should not think that way in Android. It's much more Android's way to "share" things. Look at this link, you will get it : http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent

And when an answer fits your need, feel free to accept it, that's the only way people get rewarded here.